# How is that $(1/k)^k$ derived from this power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

How is that $(\frac{1}{k})^{k}$ derived? I know it is something related to combinatorics, would you give me a proof on this, and also point me to some other useful web resource to understand this deeper?

[image]

Comment: At the end of the first line there are k factors of $n+1$ in the numerator. Each factor is assigned to the $kn+k$ term in the denominator. Apply L'hospital's rule so that each term in brackets becomes $\frac{1}{k}$ and there are k such terms.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with combinatorics. It's just the elementary limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+a}{kn+b}=\frac1k$$ where $a,b,k$ are constants. Notice that you can split the limit of the product into the product of the limits because the number of factors ($k$) is a constant which does not depend on $n$.